# Entries order in a change-set that was amended with an additional item

Tags: odata, sapui5

UI5 app runs on on-prem SAP Gateway using the library in version 1.52.

The frontend is sending two entries to SAP Gateway as a *change-set* (`setDefferredGroups`, `createEntry` [link](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel%23methods/setDeferredGroups) [link](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel%23methods/createEntry)) .

Gateway executes them in the order they were added:

```
Item1
Item2
```

As one of them fails, the entire *change-set* gets status “400 Bad request”.  Two entries contained in the *changes-set* remain marked as *Pending*.

Now, I add a third entry (item3) to a change-set expecting that `submitChanges` will send a request in *change-set* with the third entry at the end.:

```
Item1
Item2
Item3
```

But the third entry gets added as the first one:

```
Item3
Item1
Item2
```

resulting in the wrong processing order in the Gateway.

Is this the error in UI5 control?
Do you know any way around it?
How to make SAP Gateway execute new entries added for second processing in the correct order?

Comment: Issue registered with SAP https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3090